# Colouring data points in ggplot 2 based on variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a regression model and need to plot using ggplot to colour the plot based on the group variable.

```
model4 <- lm(fluid2 ~  totalPA_z + group + fluid1 + age_z + education_z + alcohol_z + socioeconomic_z, data=matches)
```

Group has the two options of "control" and "participant" and I need to separate them on the graph by different colours without ruining the current available code. Currently my plot is created as such

```
#create function for partial regression plots
avPlots.invis <- function(MODEL, ...) {
  ff <- tempfile();
  png(filename = ff);
  OUT <- car::avPlots(MODEL, ...);
  dev.off()
  unlink(ff);
  OUT; }

ggAVPLOTS  <- function(MODEL, YLAB = NULL) {
 #Extract the information for AV plots
  AVPLOTS <- avPlots.invis(MODEL);
  K       <- length(AVPLOTS);
  #Create the added variable plots using ggplot
  GGPLOTS <- vector('list', K);
  for (i in 1:K) {
  DATA         <- data.frame(AVPLOTS[[i]]);
  GGPLOTS[[i]] <- ggplot2::ggplot(aes_string(x = colnames(DATA)[1],
                                             y = colnames(DATA)[2]),
                                 data = DATA) +
                  geom_point(colour = '#000000', shape = ) +
                  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE,
                              color = '#000000', formula = y ~ x, linetype = 'solid') +
                  ggtitle("A") +
                  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=1, face="bold", size=18), axis.text=element_text(colour="black", size=12), axis.title = element_text(face="bold", colour="black", size = 12)) +
                  xlim(-2, 3) +
                  ylim (-20, 20) +
                  xlab("Total PA (adjusted)") +
                  ylab("Fluid Intelligence Score"); }
  #Return output object
  GGPLOTS; }

p1 <- ggAVPLOTS(model4)
tiff("Model4 fluid-totalPA.tiff", height = 600, width = 600)
p1[1]
```

Thank you for any assistance :)

Comment: Color is just a mapping from a column like x and y axes are: `geom_point(mapping = aes(color = group)`

Comment: I do that but states `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'group' not found`

Comment: `group` must be column of `DATA`